# Not able to apply function properly to DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with a DataFrame that looks like this:

[image: DataFrame]

I wanted to create a new column 'Named' in order to use the categorical column 'Name' in linear regression. I did the following to accomplish that goal:

```
def named(name):
if name == 'UNNAMED':
    return 0
else:
    return 1


df['Named'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda name: named(name))
```

However, that gives a column that consists only of the value 1

The function works on its own, but for some reason doesn't behave when used in the DataFrame.apply method.

Comment: which pandas version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
df['Named']=[i for i in map(lambda x: 0 if x.strip()=='UNNAMED' else 1, df['Name'])]
```

Comment: Is this UNNAMED in Name column exact UNNAMED? Maybe there are space etc?
I made a small change to code, try again please

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The "UNNAMED" is actually: '            UNNAMED'

Comment: actually, your code in the map could just be `map(named, df["Name"])`

Answer (score 1):

1. You can solve this elegantly with

```
df.assign(Named = lambda df: (df["Name"]!='UNNAMED').astype(int))
```

2. Your function is not vectorized, but apply passes the whole column, i.e. a series object to `named`. This object clearly is not equal to `UNNAMED`, hence, you get the 1. Did you try [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html)? This works for me as you desire

Moreover, on a recent pandas version, I can't reproduce your example, I'm seeing this error message:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Updated to latest pandas version, your piece of code is still only returning 1s

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The "UNNAMED" is actually: '            UNNAMED'

Comment: so with quotations? otherwise it doesn't matter. If it's with quotations, you can try `"'UNNAMED'"`. Anyway, did you try applymap?

Comment: @Aayush Panda
Great! Can you please confirm that solution is working now? If yes can you pease accept/upvote the answer?
Regards